# Proving $\dim(\ker( p (T) ) ) = n\cdot d$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $d$ is the degree of the polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A few more details: $T$ is $T : V -> V$ for some space $V$. Also, the polynomial $p$ is irreducible where $d \ge 1 $. What I've done so far was to restrict the transformation to the invariant subspace $\ker(p(T))$ and figure out that the degree of the characteristic polynomial of that restricted transform is the dimension I'm looking for.

The problem for me now is, how to show that the characteristic polynomial of the restriction is some power of $p$. I'm sure that i'm missing something very basic, but I just can't figure out how to even proceed. Any hints/help will be appreciated!

Comment: In what field are you working ? $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or any $\mathbb{K}$ ?

Comment: The field is unspecified, so it can be any field.

Comment: I've trid this : For the restriction, by definition of $ker(p(T))$, you can actually see that $p$ verifies $p(T|_{ker(p(T))})=0$.$T|_{ker(p(T))}$ is canceled by $p$, so $p$ must be divided by the minimal polynomial of $T|_{ker(p(T))}$, but $p$ is irreducible so the minimal polynomial of $T|_{ker(p(T))}$ is exactly $p$. Since the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, then $\chi_T = P^n.Q$ with $gcd(Q,P) = 1$. But I don't see now why should $Q=1$ or $degQ$ be a multiple of $d$...

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out why $p(T|_{ker(p(T))})=0$, I guess that's what was holding me back. And now because $0 \leq n $, ( its a positive integer ), means that $\chi_{ker(p(T))}$ is either the same degree or a certain degree higher than $p$. Does that seem correct?

Comment: Yes it is. More precisely, $P$ is an irreducible factor of $\chi_{T|_{KerP(T)}}$. The problem is to control the "or higher" part of the degree, that I put in a polynomial $Q$ in my previous comment. In $\mathbb{C}$ this is trivial because $d=1$, and in $\mathbb{R}$, if $d=2$ (only non trivial case), because of the fact that eigenvalues are exactly roots of $P$, and also these of $Q$ (only the multiplicity can change), then $Q$ can't introduce a "new" real root, so its degree must be pair and it works fine. But in abritrary field, I don't know...

Comment: That indeed makes sense :) I think it can be assumed that the field is either real or complex, because these are the fields we usually work with, so that indeed answers my question. Thank's a lot! Also, if you could post what you wrote as an answer, so I can mark this an answered, that will awesome.

Comment: "and also these of Q (only the multiplicity can change)" -> sorry I wanted to say "and also these of $\chi_{T|_{\ldots}}$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by the OP, since the case $d=1$ is trivial, we suppose $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ and $d=2$.

By definition of $E=Ker(P(T))$, for all $v \in E$, $P(T)(e)=0$ so $P$ cancels the endomorphism $U=T|_E$. The minimal polynomial $\mu_U$ divides $P$, but $P$ is irreducible, so $\mu_U = \alpha P$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and w.l.o.g, we can assume $\alpha=1$.

Since $P=\mu_U \mid \chi_U$, we can write $\chi_U = P^n.Q$ where $Q$ is such that $gcd(P,Q)=1$. We also know that the eigenvalues of $U$ are the roots of $\mu_U$, but also the ones of $\chi_U$, which must have the same roots. So $Q$ can't have a real root, hence $deg(Q) \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and finally $deg(\chi_U) = 2n + deg(Q) = 2n'$